# URL Rewriting using ASP.NET 3.5 with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to rewrite the URL using ASP.NET with code behind as C#. My Application contains the following URL...

> http://www.mywebsite.com/Products.aspx?id=1&pg=1

However, I need to rewrite the URL in such a way that the user gets the same contents of the above URL when the user types the following URL...

> http://www.mywebsite.com/CategoryName/ProductName/1

Can any of you guys help me with the complete necessary code how to do it?
I mean the web.config, Global.asax, etc...

Comment: Just to be clear, URL Rewriting works in reverse... You don't move the resource to be at the desired Url, you transform the requested Url so it ends up pointing at the desired resource.

Answer (score 2):

If you have IIS7, the best option would be to use [IIS Url Rewrite Module](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7435).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a couple of options I could suggest:

**One**

You could look at setting up an `HttpHandlerFactory`.

I have written one myself: http://mvcsnippets.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/custom-cms-using-httphandlerfactory.html

here is the basic gist:

```
namespace Web.Helpers {
public class HttpCMSHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url,string pathTranslated)
{
    string pageName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(context.Request.PhysicalPath);

    //on Server.Transfer the context is kept, so this just overrides the existing value.
    if (context.Items.Contains("PageName")) 
    {
        context.Items["PageName"] = pageName; } else { context.Items.Add("PageName", pageName); } 
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(context.Request.MapPath(context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath)); 

        //if File is not physical 
        if (fi.Exists == false) 
        {
             //return page to CMS handler the context containing "PageName" is passed on to this page, which then calls to the database to return the copy.
                return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(url, context.Server.MapPath("~/CMSPage.aspx"),  context);                  
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Returns real page.
            return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath, fi.FullName, context); 
        } 
    }
}
```

The behaviour I was trying to handle was that if there might be CMS content and I didnt want to have to create a page each time I needed information served, but if a physical page exists that should be returned.

For you, you might want to accept the URL, break it down to the component parts.

so `http://www.mywebsite.com/CategoryName/ProductName/1` becomes:

```
context.Items["Categoryname"] = valueFromUrlasCategoryName; 
context.Items["Productname"] = valueFromUrlasProductName; 
context.Items["Id"] = valueFromUrlasId (or pg); 

return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(url, context.Server.MapPath("~/ControlPage.aspx"),  context);
```

Then on your control page you can intercept these values from the `context` passed in and interrogate the data as needed.

In the web.config you point a reference towards your HttpHandlerFactory

```
<httphandlers>
<add path="*.aspx" type="Web.Helpers.HttpCMSHandlerFactory, Web.helpers" verb="*"/>
</httphandlers>
```

In your case you could set the path as "*.*" to capture all traffic. this would mean you would have to add handling for images and scripts.

you will also need to make sure you add a wildcard to your IIS for extensionless pages.

There are plenty of articles about [HttpHandlerFactories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720140%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on the web, and might explain better.

**Two**

The sort of thing you are after is part of `MVC`, could you look at changing your UI to use that?